# What is the drools latest stable version jar file for below class?

Tags: java, drools

We are using drools-core 3.0.6 jar file for below classes and we want to move on latest version jar. But below classes are not available in drools-core 7.62.0 jar file. What is the drools latest stable version jar file for below class?

```
org.drools.RuleBase
org.drools.RuleBaseFactory
org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder
org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilderConfiguration
org.drools.event.ObjectAssertedEvent
org.drools.event.ObjectModifiedEvent
org.drools.event.ObjectRetractedEvent
org.drools.event.WorkingMemoryEventListener
```

Comment: This is accumulating close votes for "seeking recommendations", but this is clearly not that. It's trying to upgrade drools-core from version x to version y and discovering that unsurprisingly stuff has moved (or been _re_ moved).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

None. Those packages and classes do not exist in Drools 7.x.

The entire model and algorithms have changed. Defaults have flipped, options have been subsumed, and we now deal with KieBases rather than RuleBases.

Drools 6.x -> 7.x is a doable but extremely painful migration. Anything further is out of the question. This is a rewrite, not an upgrade.

---

Several years ago I upgraded a production system from 5.0.0 to 7.22 (the latest at the time.) While I tried to first do a piecewise upgrade, it ended up being a full rewrite. It's just not avoidable: too much has changed.